# В каких случая стоит делать две и более таблиц в базе данных для похожих сущностей?

Tags: sql, база-данных

я новичок в разработке - подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком случае, если такие есть, имеет смысл создавать более одной таблицы для похожих сущностей?
Например: Есть список задач, это одна таблица. Но каждая задача может принадлежать разным юзерам. Если у нас 1000 юзеров и у каждого по 1000 задач, то это миллион строк в таблице.
На сколько адекватен вариант создавать каждому пользователю отдельную таблицу?
Возможно, глупый вопрос, но в похожих тема обсуждали примеры, в которых я бы сам не стал делать больше одной таблицы. А в этом случае не очень понимаю - какой вариант более адекватный.
Я предполагаю, будет проблема в поддержке этих таблиц, но как тогда решается проблема с миллионом строк и проблема ли это?

Comment: А одна и та же задача может быть более чем у одного юзера?

Comment: По задумке точно не может

Comment: *На сколько адекватен вариант создавать каждому пользователю отдельную таблицу?* В указанных условиях это нет "похожие сущности", это одна и та же сущность. Поэтому создание отдельных таблиц - неадекватно. Исключение - надо обеспечить отсутствие доступа одних юзеров к информации других, а безопасность на уровне записей в данной СУБД не реализована. *как тогда решается проблема с миллионом строк и проблема ли это?* Миллион строк - это на границе малого и среднего объёмов данных.

Comment: @Александр Тогда достаточно иметь две таблицы. Юзеры и Задачи. Задачи имеют foreign key на первичный ключ пользователя.

Comment: Не стал бы рекомендовать Вам подходы задекларированные выше. В особенности не могу согласиться с Akina, т.к. отсутствие избыточности данных - это одна из основополагающих концепций реляционных БД. Одна таблица для пользователя, одна для задач и одна промежуточная с внешними ключами на пользователя и задачу. Такой подход не сильно усложнит код/запросы, но будет более гибок. Например поддержка задач назначенная нескольким пользователям, делегирование задачи другому пользователю и т.д. и т.п..

Comment: Извиняюсь перед Akina, не правильно понял комментарий.

Comment: @Александр в ТЗ явно указано 1 юзер = 1 задача, зачем усложнять и какой смысл в этой "гибкости", если она не нужна? И придумываете дальше задачи которые не нужны по ТЗ) Начинать надо всегда с простого.  А, вообще, неплохая тема для урока.

Comment: Уточните: _похожие_ или _одинаковые_ сущности? У вас именно _одинаковые_ задачи, судя по описанию. А вот для _похожих_ сущностей, имеющих совпадающие и различающиеся поля (колонки) есть варианты.

Comment: Миллион строк - это в общем-то мало. Но если всё же возникнут проблемы при увеличении их количества и/или при наличии полей больших размеров, то в современных СУБД есть немало вариантов их решения. Например, механизм TOAST в Postgres (в других БД есть аналогичные возможности), partitioning и пр.

Comment: @InDevX *в ТЗ явно указано 1 юзер = 1 задача* Цитирую автора: "у нас 1000 юзеров и **у каждого по 1000 задач**". Вы три нуля потеряли... Может, вы говорите об обратной зависимости - **1 задача => 1 юзер**? Если бы автор был убеждён в абсолютности этой истины, то да, нужно было бы сделать юзера атрибутом задачи - но вот именно этой убеждённости в его словах и нет.

Comment: @XelaNimed Тут с учетом комментария описана типичная связь ManyToOne. Можно искуственно усложнить до ManyToMany на будущее, котого может не будет. И усложнить себе жизнь + замедлить запросы.

Comment: @Akina я не так комментарий понял, каюсь. Если бы автор был убежден то не было бы вопроса)

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за помощь! Я погугил тонкости и термины из ваших ответов и понял вашу позицию - принципиально неправильно делить таблицы под каждого юзера для одной и той же сущности в реляционной СУБД.
Из интереса я попробовал начать работать над реализацией с таблицами под каждого юзера и понял, как тяжело будет это обслуживать.
Однако, есть ощущение, что такой подход может иметь своё слабое место - если у каждой задачи будет ещё комментарии, то, допускаю, могут быть случаи, когда будет 1000x1000x1000 комментариев.
Но, опять же, я понял - есть решения. Спасибо

Comment: На ютубе я нашёл предполагаемую архитектуру sql-базы для Trello - по структуре как вы мне и предложили. На деле оказалось, что Trello использует MongoBD и совсем другую концепцию.
Если что, извиняюсь, задача действительно не столько практическая, сколько теоретическая - мне просто стало интересно, где границы у подхода. 
Но, видимо, придёт с практикой.
Пока остановился на вашем варианте реализации, спасибо большое всем!